# How to make twain drivers of Twain scanner to be detected by Image Capture in Mac OS X (cocoa programming)

Tags: macos, image-capture, twain, image-scanner

I am having the twain drivers(Mac Compatibility) of the twain scanner(panasonic). I installed the divers into my Mac machine and the drivers were installed in the path : Library ▸ Image Capture ▸ TWAIN Data Sources folder.

After the installation of the drivers I tried connecting the Twain scanner(Panasonic) to my mac machine. I tried to view the connected scanner in Image capture app and it shows device list as empty. Even I tried with checking the scanners connected in printers and scanners there also shows no scanners connected.

I went through some questions in SO's where they say to for detecting the Twain scanners have to use Twain interface.

But my requirements is I want to make the twain drivers detectable by Image capture and want to see the Twain scanner in Image Capture app.

Any suggestions : How can I make the twain comparable scanners detected by Image Capture app?